# Post File object within an array of object with Axios?

Tags: file, post, axios

Are we able to upload File objs within an object with other keys? I've been asked to add an import_type key to an object, but its already a File obj when I'm upload it using a package called react-dropzone https://react-dropzone.js.org/
So I'd have to do something like

```
[{file: //File obj,
import_type: 1
}, {file: //File obj,
import_type: 1
},]
```

This is being sent in a post request

```
export const uploadFiles = (formData) => {
  return axios.post("/upload", formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  });
};
```

I'm getting an error "Missing Data" and it is only showing this as the data sent...

```
data: ["file": {"path": "",} //file path
"import_type": 1 //value I want sent with the obj
```

Answer (score 0):

Source of issue: I was passing in an entire array and axios was not looking for that but a single file.

My solution: I'm mapping through the array instead and using Promise.all for each array value so that it will be processed properly.